# using an anonymous array in a ranged for loop in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, anonymous

Is there any way to use an anonymous array in a ranged for loop?
I'm trying to do something like this

```
for(auto i: {1,2,3,5,7,11,17}) //do something
```

Comment: I don't know. I was reading about c++11 so I expected that to work. I tried it in visual studio 2012 but it didn't work.

Comment: This one works in VS 2015: `enum NotesType { HAS_TEXT, EMPTY_NOTE }; for (NotesType notesType : {HAS_TEXT, EMPTY_NOTE}) { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is; it looks like this:

```
#include <initializer_list>  //MUST INCLUDE THIS!

for(auto i: {1,2,3,5,7,11,17}) //do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have trouble because there is no type ... instead of auto declare "i" as integer.

regards

Comment: `auto` changed meaning in C++11.